# SQLCE: How to Count Datepart

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

For a long time I am struggling with the following subject: I want to count datepart values. I use SQL Compact Edition 4.0 and have no idea on how to get the following:

```
select datepart(week, CreateDate) as Week, count(*) from tblOrders 
where CreateDate>'12 April 2010' and CreateDate<'25 June 2011'
```

This does not work obviously, but to give you an idea what I want to get as the result is:
- 2 columns,

- one called "week" - that would be a week number
- in the second column - how many orders I had per week

Thanks in advance,

Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a Group By to make the query syntax correct.

```
select datepart(week, CreateDate) as Week, count(*) 
from tblOrders  where CreateDate>'12 April 2010' and CreateDate<'25 June 2011'
group by datepart(week, CreateDate)
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly what I wanted. By a mistake I used order by ... ;) Thank you anyway!